# Calling javascript functions using (this) from an unrelated tag

Tags: javascript, function, hover, onmouseover

I've built the following slideshow that retrieves the contents of...

```
<li title=""> and <a title="">
```

...and displays it inside an

```
<h2> & <h3>
```

....below while hovering over each slideshow picture. When onmouseover isn't active the heading tags are cleared and return to their default states.

HTML:

```
<ul class="slideshow">
    <li id="picture-1" title="Picture Title" onmouseover="pictureTitle(this)" onmouseout="clearPicture()">
        <a title="Picture Description" onmouseover="pictureDescription(this)" href="#">   
            <img src="images/picture-1.png">
        </a>
    </li>
    <li id="picture-2" title="Picture 2 Title" onmouseover="pictureTitle(this)" onmouseout="clearPicture()">
        <a title="Picture 2 Description" onmouseover="pictureDescription(this)" href="#">   
            <img src="images/picture-2.png">
        </a>
    </li>
    <li id="picture-3" title="Picture 3 Title" onmouseover="pictureTitle(this)" onmouseout="clearPicture()">
        <a title="Picture 3 Description" onmouseover="pictureDescription(this)" href="#">   
            <img src="images/picture-3.png">
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>

<h2 id="picture-notitle">Default Picture Title</h2>
<h2 id="picture-title"></h2>
<h3 id="picture-nodescription">Default Picture Description</h3>
<h3 id="picture-description"></h3>
```

Javascript:

```
function pictureTitle(li) {
    var name = document.getElementById("picture-title");
    name.innerText = li.title;
    name.style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById("picture-notitle").style.display = "none";
}

function pictureDescription(a) {
    var description = document.getElementById("picture-description");
    description.innerText = a.title
    description.style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById("picture-nodescription").style.display = "none";
}

function clearPicture() {
    document.getElementById("picture-notitle").style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById("picture-title").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("picture-nodescription").style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById("picture-description").style.display = "none";
}
```

CSS:

```
#picture-title, #picture-description {
    display: none;
}
```

The slideshow works as intended; hovering a picture shows its "title" and "description". I'm having trouble building onto it though. I'd like to be able to have the pictureTitle() and pictureDescription() functions called when hovering over a set of text as well, not the actual images themselves.

```
<h1>
    <span>Picture 1</span>
    <span>Picture 2</span>
    <span>Picture 3</span>
</h1>
```

I've tried calling the functions using onmouseover on the span tag, but haven't been able to get anything working.

Any ideas?

Comment: Why do you have events on both the LI and the A tags? Why not call both functions from the A-tag?

Comment: I tried and was unsuccessful. The contents of a title attribute was the only thing I've been able to retrive and since you can't have two title attributes I split it between the li and a.

Comment: Would you consider using jQuery? This make it 10x easier. I will post an answer to that if you want to use it.

Comment: Absolutely! I'd appreciate that.

Comment: I'm working on it. Back soon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, here we go...

One beauty of jQuery is you can select elements easily, and hook up event handlers at RUN TIME, leaving you with cleaner code. Another benefit is you can also stash data elements in your HTML, so you end up with cleaner, leaner HTML:

```
<ul class="slideshow">
   <li>
        <a data-title="Picture Title" data-description="Picture Description" href="#">   
            <img src="images/picture-1.png">
        </a>
    </li>
...
```

You need to hook up event handlers AFTER the page is ready. This bit of code calls a function called "init" when the DOM is ready.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    init()
});

    function init() {
        $(".slideshow a").on("mouseover",function(event) {     
            $("#picture-title").show().html($(this).data('title'));           
            $("#picture-description").show().html($(this).data('description'));
            $("#picture-notitle").hide()
            $("#picture-nodescription").hide()
        });
        $('.slideshow a').on("mouseout", function(event){
            $("#picture-notitle, #picture-nodescription").show()
            $("#picture-title, #picture-description").hide()
        });
    }
```

Explained:

`$(".className")` gives you an array of all elements matching a class name.

`$("#elementID")` gives you the element matching an ID

`$(this)` gives you the current element, which in your case is the on that fired the specified event (mouseover/mouseout). This is handy in that you don't need to handle or pass an element ID.

jQuery allows you to stack commands:

```
$("#picture-title").show().html($(this).data('title'));
```

This selects the element, shows it, then sets the HTML based on the element's own "data-title" value. Three steps in one line of code.

The rest is simply using the data- elements and show() and hide(), which are pretty obvious.